# Node.JS Winston logging, Visual Studio Debug Console Not Print

Tags: node.js

When running as "node app" on terminal of visual studio code during winston logging, console log is output.
However, the debug console tab of visual studio does not print the console log.
Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZ2W.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf1kj.png)

Comment: console.log print only in controller.js it won't print in server side

Comment: It is not shown cause at internal level `console.log` is a wrapper of the `process.stdout`, io operation but `winston` is  simple program which you need to specifically configure to write to the output.

Answer (score 6):

below is my launch.json
the key is `"outputCapture": "std",`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "outputCapture": "std", //key is this line
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion about tests running in debug mode?